# Do something when local notification arrives or exceed the number of total notifications that can be used

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification, alarm, localnotification

So, I have an exercise app where we have 10/15 Second repetitive timers through which we show the progress done by the User. For making it work on background as well, I have used local notifications. However, as stated by Apple, we can only have **[ONLY 64 local notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1)** at any given instance of our app.

So, what happens now is when app is in background and these 64 notifications have finished, I have no control over the app. I can re-add the 64 notifications if the User opens the app. But if User doesn't open the app at all and these 64 notifications are finished then what should I do?

Is there any event which occurs inside the app when any local notification arrives? Is there any way to exceed the number of notifications?

I think there should be a solution as there are many **Alarm Apps** which work on the same methodology.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`repeatInterval` property of `UILocalNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/repeatInterval) to make your notification automatically repeat every second, minute, hour, day, or other unit (see [`NSCalendarUnit` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSCalendarUnit)):

```
notification.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
```

For your case, this means that you can create 5 notifications with `fireDate`s 10 seconds apart, each with a `repeatInterval` of `NSMinuteCalendarUnit`. This will result in the user receiving a notification every 10 seconds indefinitely, and you will have only scheduled 5 notifications, which is well below the limit of 64.

The only downside of this technique is that there will be no way to stop the notifications until the user opens the app, as you will need to cancel all the notifications to stop them, and you can only do that while the app is running.

Comment: Perfect! However, just a doubt that couldn't you just assign the repeatInterval = 10 or should it just be a calendarUnit only ??

Comment: It can only be an `NSCalendarUnit`. `repeatInterval` uses the `enum` values of `NSCalendarUnit`, so you can't just assign an arbitrary value and expect it to understand it.

Comment: There are a number of people complaining about this (especially [here](http://www.dueapp.com/faq.html#snoozelimitations)), but Apple hasn't done anything in the way of adding custom repeat intervals, so I guess you should join the complaining by filing a [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: can we add notification with
Start date till end date at 5 different time in a day ????

Comment: @iphonemaclover no. You'll have to schedule multiple notifications.

Comment: @iphonemaclover if you have a specific problem, you should ask a new question so more people can help you.

Comment: i asked but dont get solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27579432/set-multiple-uilocalnotification

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this.

No delegate will be called if a notification comes when your app is in killed state or in background.

Note:

Only 64 local notification can be scheduled at a time. Possibly the alarm apps are using the `repeatInterval` property of [UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Eg:

```
notification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
```

It'll repeat each day.

Comment: @mayuur: did you know any alarm app with such a feature ? if yes please share it's link.

Answer (score 1):

I have an exercise app that does the same thing and I had the same problem. 
My solution was to put all the timers into a "pending" queue and then schedule the local notifications from that queue.

On first run - when the user presses Go - while the (number of notifications < 64) && (pending queue count > 0), remove each timer from the pending queue and add it to the notifications queue.

Each time the app launches, in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions in the appDelegate check whether ([notificationsQueue count] < 64 && [pendingQueue count > 0]) and top up the notifications queue. If there are more than 64 in the pending queue, they remain there until the app is launched and there is space in the notifications queue.

The queue system works just perfectly.

It doesn't get round the problem of the user not opening the app within 64 notifications, however, in my testing users didn't ever get close to creating 64 exercise timers and rarely made it past 30. Also, it's quite common for the user to open the app to pause a timer, at which point the queue logic deals with topping up the notifications.

I've never had a single problem with this method. Then again, if your timers are identical (10/15seconds) a repeatInterval will do the job as PartiallyFinite wrote... while I was writing this : )

The end.

Steve

Comment: Yes, I implemented the same earlier. But as you already know, this won't be possible for timers of 10/15 seconds!

Answer (score -1):

This method is called in AppDelegate when a local notification is received. You can do what ever you want here.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"recieved notification %@", notification);
}
```

Comment: this method gets called only when user would open up the app which isn't what I want

Comment: **without opening the app you cannot do anything with your app**

Comment: To my knowledge they are using local notification only. They can set maximum 64 notifications. I think it is enough since the old notifications getting cancelled when you open the app.